# python docx Como poder obtener los formatos deseados en el estilo sustituido? Y si son dos formatos distintos?

Tags: python-3.x, docx, python-docx

Dentro de un carpeta tengo varios documentos de Microsoft Word *.docx, a los cuales les quiero sustituir una información que es común para todos, previa modificación con palabras claves, que tienen como formato PYTHON-TEXTO1,PYTHON-TEXTO2, etc.

Para hacerlo utilizo la librería docx de python.

En la búsqueda y sustitución no hay problema, pero podríamos hablar de dos casos:
1 caso: Información que se busca dentro de una tabla EN UN SOLO DOCUMENTO que debe tener el siguiente formato:
•   font.size = Pt(22)

•   font.name = ‘Arial’

•   font.underline = False

2 caso: Información que se sustituye en el resto del documento, tanto dentro como fuera de tablas es este:

•   font.size = Pt(12)

•   font.name = ‘Arial’

•   font.underline = True

Porque cuando se hace la sustitucion de la palabra clave no queda con el formato que tenia anteriormente, lo deseado es:

En la caratula:
C: INFORMACION1.
Arial 22 subrayado, no afectando el encabezado

y en lo demás:
Nombre del servicio: informacion2.
Arial 12 Subrayado no afectando el encabezado

Aqui el codigo que produce resultados no deseados, aunque ya he leido ejemplos y documentacion

```
from os import listdir  # esta libreria es para manipular ficheros, etc

import docx # esta libreria es para manipular documentos word(.docx)

from docx import Document

from docx.shared import Pt

nuevo_codigo = input('Teclee nuevo codigo: ')
nuevo_servicio = input('Teclee nuevo servicio: ')
nuevo_cobjeto = input('Teclee nuevo codigo del objeto: ')
nuevo_objeto = input('Teclee nuevo objeto: ')
nuevo_cliente = input('Teclee nuevo cliente: ')

# path donde se ubicara el documento a leer.
path_reporte = "D:/Escritorio/WORD PYTHON"

#defino lista para despues anhadirle los nombres de los documentos y del path

lista_documentos = []
lista_path = []

# itero para obtener lo que hay en el path
for documento in listdir(path_reporte):

    lista_documentos.append(documento) # obtengo el nombre del documento del path
    lista_path.append(path_reporte + '/' + documento) # concateno el string para obtener el path total

print(lista_path,lista_documentos)

# esto es para la caratula nada mas, que es la que esta dentro de una tabla

for i in lista_path:

    doc = docx.Document(i) # voy a trabajar con los documentos en el path i

    #esta es la estructura para poder llegarle a lo que esta dentro de la tabla: 

    for tabla in doc.tables: 

        for columna in tabla.columns:

            for celda in columna.cells:

                for j in celda.paragraphs:

                    if '0.Carátula.docx' in i:

                        #estilos para los textos a sustituir dentro de tablas:
                        run = doc.add_paragraph().add_run()
                        style = doc.styles['Normal']
                        font = style.font

                        font.name = 'Arial'
                        font.size = Pt(22)
                        font.underline = False
                        
                        j.style = doc.styles['Normal']
                        doc.add_page_break()

                    else:

                        #estilos para los textos fuera de las tablas:

                        run = doc.add_paragraph().add_run()
                        style = doc.styles['Normal']
                        font = style.font

                        font.name = 'Arial'
                        font.size = Pt(12)
                        font.underline = True

                        j.style = doc.styles['Normal']
                        doc.add_page_break()

                    if 'PYTHON-CODIGO' in j.text:

                        j.text = j.text.replace('PYTHON-CODIGO',nuevo_codigo)

                    elif 'PYTHON-SERVICIO' in j.text:

                        j.text = j.text.replace('PYTHON-SERVICIO', nuevo_servicio)

                    elif 'PYTHON-COBJETO' in j.text:

                        j.text = j.text.replace('PYTHON-COBJETO', nuevo_cobjeto)
                    
                    elif 'PYTHON-OBJETO' in j.text:

                        j.text = j.text.replace('PYTHON-OBJETO',nuevo_objeto)

                    elif 'PYTHON-CLIENTE' in j.text:

                        j.text = j.text.replace('PYTHON-CLIENTE',nuevo_cliente)

                                    

    doc.save(i)
    print('Trabajo en tablas guardado',i)



# esto es para todos los documentos fuera de las tablas

    
    for j in doc.paragraphs:

        #estilos para los textos fuera de las tablas:

        run = doc.add_paragraph().add_run()
        style = doc.styles['Normal']
        font = style.font

        font.name = 'Arial'
        font.size = Pt(12)
        font.underline = True

        j.style = doc.styles['Normal']
        doc.add_page_break()

        

        if 'PYTHON-CODIGO' in j.text:

            j.text = j.text.replace('PYTHON-CODIGO',nuevo_codigo)

        elif 'PYTHON-SERVICIO' in j.text:

            j.text = j.text.replace('PYTHON-SERVICIO', nuevo_servicio)

        elif 'PYTHON-COBJETO' in j.text:

            j.text = j.text.replace('PYTHON-COBJETO', nuevo_cobjeto)
        
        elif 'PYTHON-OBJETO' in j.text:

            j.text = j.text.replace('PYTHON-OBJETO',nuevo_objeto)

        elif 'PYTHON-CLIENTE' in j.text:

            j.text = j.text.replace('PYTHON-CLIENTE',nuevo_cliente)

        
    doc.save(i)
    print('Trabajo en el resto del documento guardado',i)
```

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: por lo que he podido estudiar , la opcion planteada no es la deseada pues cuando se sustituye la palabra encontrada, cambia tambien el formato del parrafo y se crean otros resultados no placenteros, por lo que en mi opinion doy por terminado este post, en vista de que he encontrado una mejor solucion

Comment: Esta es la reformulacion de la pregunta, pues de esta otra forma he logrado mas avances https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/368219/python-docx-encontrar-palabras-en-tabla-y-sustituir-error